# How to bitbake dynamic layer recipes in Yocto?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to bitbake this recipe by

```
bitbake cryptoauthlib
```

but my yocto project is not able to find the recipe in the layer. Although layer is already added into the bblayers file

https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/122514/

How can i add the recipe from dynamic layer into my yocto image?

Comment: What's the output you get while trying to build the recipe ?

Comment: @ogs , i didnt know that i also have to clone the meta_aws layer as well. it worked now. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @ogs, do you know how to packagegroup the recipes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816341/how-to-integrate-external-recipes-into-yocto-image-using-packagegroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from the meta-atmel git repository that i also needed to clone the meta-aws layer. Then it worked.
so, clone the https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-aws/ layer and try bitbaking it again.

and also if you want to use systemd instead of sysvinit, try replacing 'eudev' with 'udev' here: https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/blob/dunfell/dynamic-layers/aws-layer/recipes-security/cryptoauthlib/cryptoauthlib_git.bb#L11  [Source: meta-atmel github repo]